# Get specific data from website using python

Tags: python, html

i want to get specific data from a website.

The url of the website is https://www.bullmarketbrokers.com/Cotizaciones/Acciones.

I want to get 'P.Compra' value for 'Producto'. I know how to use BeatifulSoup to get the html code. But i don't know how to extract the information.

Comment: Can you add any code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use BeautifulSoup to scrape the page when [the API the site is using itself](https://www.bullmarketbrokers.com/Information/StockPrice/GetStockPrices?term=3&index=merval&sortColumn=ticker&isAscending=true) is available.
(For sites that seem to dynamically load data, you can find the URLs and requests being made through your browser's console.)

The following

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://www.bullmarketbrokers.com/Information/StockPrice/GetStockPrices?term=3&index=merval&sortColumn=ticker&isAscending=true').json()
for symbol in data['result']:
  print(symbol['ticker'], symbol['stockOffer']['bidTop'][0]['quantity'])
```

prints out

```
ALUA 5900 
APBR 514  
BMA 3114  
BYMA 180  
CEPU 20   
COME 20250
CRES 1    
CVH 84    
DGCU2 50  
EDN 200   
GGAL 49363
LOMA 425  
METR 2310 
MIRG 10   
PAMP 1000 
SUPV 449  
TECO2 4608
TGNO4 229 
TGSU2 225 
TRAN 64   
TS 242    
TXAR 6326 
VALO 1200 
YPFD 10
```

which seem to correspond to the column you want.